Webactity in synapse fails if the restapi returns 400 response or any other HTTPS Error?
AzureSynpase I am calling webActity in for loop, as I am required to call webActity for each record in a table which had 'custid', Now I see some 'custid' is not present in server DB it returns a 400 error. But webActity shows failed and we get alert always ???
is there a way I can handle or catch such an exception and make it a success this is not a failure which I am looking for until and unless I receive a syntax error I need to show a successful response.
is there any Actity which I can use to handle such ??? As see it do not have any control over that ??

To avoid the exception which causing because of sometimes web activity get the wrong input and it process this. To catch the correct input, you can use if activity in synapse pipeline where it will check the input and execute activity accordingly.
You need to use the If activity under foreach activity and pass the item to if activity to check the input by using dynamic expressions like below:
@not(equals(item().custid,null))

The above expression will return true if input is not null and execute the activities under the true section.


No this is not a problem item().custid comes from table and when I use restapi it comes as failed now my Webactity is showing failed as the response from server is not a valid custid....I am saying this response is correct I will parse the response and then only I can add check ryt
